# countdown javascript with start and end

Tags: javascript, countdown

Mayday mayday, can someone help me
How to make countdown timer from firstvisit time until end time (read date time from server)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    liftoffTime=new Date(<?php echo $serverTimeEndTest;?>);
    $("‪#‎timer‬").countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS', expiryUrl:"/urlExpired"});
    function serverTime() {
      var time = null;
      $.ajax({url: "/ServerTimes",
        async: false, dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
          time = new Date(text);
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) {
          time = new Date();
        }
      });
      return time;
    }
});
```

I use this script

```
$("#timer").countdown({since:new Date(<?php echo $startVisit;?>),until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS', expiryUrl:"/urlExpired"});
```

The time showing 00:00:00 and expired

Help me out

Thanks

Comment: If you are able to get end-time in `$serverTimeEndTest`, then why do you need ajax ?

Comment: Because when the client online, countdown time be different results if the date in a client different. I want a client and a server is always the same. 
Example

Server: 09-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
Client: 09-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
Countdown until 120 minutes

The result countdown from 02:00:00 until 00:00:00

But if the time on the client computer 08-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
The result countdown from 26:00:00 until 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Because when the client online, countdown time be different results if the date in a client different. I want a client and a server is always the same.

Example

Server: 09-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
Client: 09-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
Countdown until 120 minutes

The result countdown from 02:00:00 until 00:00:00

But if the time on the client computer 08-02-2016 04:07:10 PM
The result countdown from 26:00:00 until 00:00:00